# Entire grid content is not getting exported when exporting entire page as pdf using kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, pdf-generation

I was trying to export a page to pdf using kendo which has a couple of grids. All works good when the grid contains a few records. The issue comes up when the grid contains more data (i.e. scrollable data). When I export the pdf now the grid shows only the data in the current view. The entire data in the grid does not show up. How can I accomplish this?

I have modified a dojo example that I found in the forums to demonstrate the issue.
http://dojo.telerik.com/igIseD

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the desired result, you need to export the Grid via its own internal PDF exporting mechanism. Here is a similar example:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/pdf-export/all-page-content-with-all-pages